# Classical lagrangian spin SU(2)

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, spin-geometry

In which sense is the configuration variable of a classical spin SU(2)? I can view a classical spin as a unit vector in S^2 (2dim sphere), but it seems it is really given by a matrix U in SU(2). The Hopf map $H:SU(2)\rightarrow S^2$ given by $H(U)=U\sigma_3U^{\dagger}$ whose image can be identified with an element in $S^2$ gives what I imagined to be this classical spin.

Since with a magnetic field $B$ the interaction is just $H(U) \cdot B$ there would be no problem on just considering $S \in S^2$ as a configuration variable, but I read the following:

A classical particle of mass $m$, with position $x$ and spin $S$ moving on a fixed external magnetic field $B$ can be described by the Lagrangian function on the tangent bundle of the configuration space $\mathbb{R} \times SU(2)$ given as

$L=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2+i\lambda Tr(\sigma_3U^{\dagger}\dot{U})+\mu Tr(H(U)\dot B)$

So the second term is explicitly in terms of $U$.

Thank you

EDIT: EDIT: I got this from "Gauge symmetries and fiber bundles". Balachandran et al.

[image: pq19 of ref]

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. What do you want to know about the model? It seems to be a semi-classical model in the sense that the particle trajectory is treated classically, but the spin is treated quantum mechanically. Is it maybe the Lagrangian for the Stern-Gerlach experiment?

Comment: I can see a "classical" spining particle being described by $u \in S^2$.

Comment: But why as an element in $SU(2)$? And how do I understand the 2nd term in the Lagrangian?

Comment: A good reference is Gauge Symmetries and Fiber Bundles, Balachandran, but it isn't that clear to me

Comment: But who is saying that the model you wrote down is for a "classical" spinning particle? I don't agree.

Comment: The energy for the interaction of a classical spin with a magnetic field is $E=\vec{\mu}\cdot\vec{B}$. If you normalize the magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}=\mu\vec{\sigma}$ where $\vec{\sigma}$ is indeed an element of $S^2$.

Comment: page 19 of the reference I wrote (Balachandran)

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185176/2451

Comment: @Raskolnikov see EDIT